# 500 - Internal server error in azure

Tags: azure

I am using `SDK 1.8`.I want to deploy a sample site in azure.I have a test account so I don't know I have full privilege or not.When I run a site locally using simulator its run but  when I create a package and deploy in azure I got a error:

```
500 - Internal server error
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6275462/azure-management-api-returns-500-internal-server-error)  with same problem.Its 5 months old with no solution.I include in `web.config`:

```
customErrors="Off"
```

But still same problm.I deploy this as a site with create a package.

I search but never found any solution.May some body face same problem and get a solution.Thanks.

Comment: share more details please!  MVC 4 / .NET 4.5?  URL?  Have you tried setting customErrors="Off" to get a full stack trace? code? deployment method?

Comment: @viperguynaz  yap customErrors="Off" but still get same error.And using .NET 4.5.

Comment: deploying to a Azure site or service? and how are you deploying?

Comment: @viperguynaz as a site.Thanks for quick reply.Create a package. My .csdef file looks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050234/physicaldirectory-and-redirection-in-azure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure websites aren't deployed as packages, you publish from TFS or Visual Studio.  Azure WebRoles are deployed to Azure Cloud Services using packages.  As recommended in the question you [referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14050234/physicaldirectory-and-redirection-in-azure), remove the "sites" element completely.  It is over-specified for a simple deployment.  See figure 1 here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_advancedwebandworkerroles_topic2.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to debug this locally using the compute emulator.  Even if your not using it now to get something quick working on the cloud, you'll need it in the future.

One way to help get more descriptive output is to enable detailed error messages rather than the one you're seeing at the moment.

This isn't as easy as enabling custom errors and requires some tinkering with the web role.  This article '[Debugging Azure HTTP 500 Errors](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/11/06/debugging-azure-http-500-errors.aspx)' explains how to do it, so, in a nutshell:

Create a new folder at the root level of your web role called startup and, within this folder, create a batch file called `startup.cmd`. Set the properties of this file to Copy Always to ensure that it will be deployed.

Add the following code to the `startup.cmd` file:

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\AppCmd.exe set config -section:system.webServer/httpErrors -errorMode:Detailed 
%APPCMD% set config -section:system.webServer/httpErrors -errorMode:Detailed
```

The first line enables detailed error messages on Azure. The second line enables them on the compute emulator.

Next, open the `ServiceDefinition.csdef` file in your web role project and add the following element:

```
<Startup>
    <Task commandLine=”..\startup\startup.cmd” executionContext=”elevated” />
</Startup>
```

Your project will should look something like this *(in this example the startup tag is  commented out)*:

[image]

If all goes well, you should start seeing more useful and descriptive error messages.

Answer (score 0):

It can be due to various reasons. 
In my case it was **misconfiguration** of the LocalWebDevelopmentServer setting. Setting it to `IISExpress` fixed the problem.[image]